# How can I produce semibold within a textsanskrit command?

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia

I'm creating complex documents with LuaLateX, and there is a problem specifying font weights. It appears to be a clash between fontspec and polyglossia. When the language is defined with polyglossia it doesn't want to select any weights other than standard ones.

I'm using `\textsanskrit` , Arno Pro, and semibold as my use case, but I think it applies generally to selecting weights with these two packages.

Here's the MWE:.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{Arno Pro}
\newfontfamily\Semiboldnormalfont[]{Arno Pro Semibold}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[]{english}
\setotherlanguage[script=latin]{sanskrit}

\newcommand*{\usesemiboldfont}[1]{{\Semiboldnormalfont{#1}}}

\begin{document}%

\begin{enumerate}

% plain works fine
\item four \textsanskrit{kaṁsa} coins. 

% desired markup, but textsanskrit is not semibold
\item \usesemiboldfont{four \textsanskrit{kaṁsa} coins.}

% desired result, but fussy markup
\item \usesemiboldfont{four \textsanskrit{\usesemiboldfont{kaṁsa}} coins. }

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I want to use markup like item two, and get the result like item three. One of the reasons this matters is that the markup is produced by a custom conversion from HTML, and identifying these cases conditionally based on their context would not be trivial. So i'm looking for something I can do hopefully just in the preamble.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to reproduce your example with a commercial font. Can you reproduce the issue with a free font, preferably one that already ships with LaTeX?